# Question About Definition Of $\sigma$- Algebra Generated By Random Variable $X$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In Book Of  Measure, Integral and Probability By Marek Capinski and Ekkehard Kopp on page $67$ :
Author says if random variable $X$ takes two values $a\neq b$ .then $\sigma(X)$  ($\sigma$- algebra generated by $X$) contain $4$ element. i.e
$$ \sigma(X)=\left \{\phi,\Omega,X^{-1} \{a\},X^{-1} \{b\}\right\} \tag{1}$$

.Now by definition for random variable $X$  ,$\sigma$ -algebra generated by $X$ is

$$ \sigma(X)=\left \{A\subset\Omega :A=X^{-1}\{B\} ~\text{for some}~ B \in B(\Bbb R)\right\}$$

So what author wants to say here ? Here collection in equation $(1)$ may not be $\sigma$ -algebra.

If we assume $X$ takes  two values $a$ and $b$ **means** $P(X=a)+P(X=b)=1$ . then My thought on this is collection in equation (1) **somehow** contain enough information about $X$ . For if  $Y$ is another random variable then

> X and Y are independent iff collection in equation (1) and $\sigma(Y)~$are independent.

For  If side

Let $A=X^{-1}\{C\}$ for some $C\in B(\Bbb R)$ and $B\in \sigma (Y)$ .

**case 1**:

If $a ,b \notin C$  then $P(A)=0$  .So A and B are independent.

**case 2:**

if $a\in C$ and $b\notin C$ . then $$ A= X^{-1}\{a\} \cup X^{-1}\{C\setminus \{a\}\}$$ .
So by hypothesis and fact that $P\left(X^{-1}\{C\setminus \{a\}\}\right)=0$ we  have  $X^{-1}\{C\setminus \{a\}\}$ , $X^{-1}\{a\}$ ,and $B$ are independent . hence $A$ and $B$ are independent. Case $3$ is Similar to Case $2$.

Now my questions are

> $(1)$ : Is my above proof correct ?

> $(2)$: If it is then it is true even if $X$ takes finite values ?

> $(3)$ : What author means by declaring collection in equation (1) by sigma algebra generated by $X$.

Comment: The assumption that $X$ *takes two values* $a\neq b$ means that $a,b$ are *the only values* of $X$, i.e., for each $\omega\in \Omega$ (the domain of $X$) you have $X(\omega)\in\{a,b\}$. Then the statement (1) is correct.

Comment: @Jochen  Yes Then it is true